# How to check data in oracle Nosql via client?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I started kvlite using :

`java -jar /lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -store OracleNoSqlTests`

I opened client using:

`java -jar lib/kvcli.jar -host localhost -port 5000`

Then I fired `show table` I got all the tables under this store.

**Is there any way to check data of a table via client?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First, you have to connect to your store

```
connect store -name OracleNoSqlTests
```

Then you can query a table with:

```
 get table -name <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>
```

You can also filter by primary key

```
get table -name <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> -field <PK_FIELD> -value <VALUE>
```

If your primary key consists of multiple fields, just repeat the field/value pairs for each component of the key.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but just to let you know, we now provide the ability to do SQL queries so you can really do SWR queries for e.g. select * from Users where firstName = "John"

Here's the grammar:

```
sfw_expr :
 select_clause
 from_clause
 where_clause?
 orderby_clause?
 limit_clause?
 offset_clause? ;
```